# Construction of a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $Z[X]$ denote the ring of polynomials in $X$ with integer coefficients .Find an ideal $I$ in $Z[X]$ such that $Z[X]/I$ is a field of order $4$.

My attempt:I know that if $F$ is a  field & $f(x)$ is irreducible in $F[X]$ then $F[X]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ is  a field.If  we take $F =Z_p$ & $f(x)$ as  an $2$ degree polynomial then such a construction is possible.But not sure how to proceed here

Comment: Is making your posting less readable really worth the extra effort of typing "&" rather than "and"?

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb Z[X]/\langle p \rangle \cong \Bbb Z_p[X]$. So what happens when $I$ contains both $p$ and a monic degree two irreducible polynomial?

Comment: Sorry to bother you sir but is this a standard result or requires some deduction .I have just started polynomial rings

Comment: You should be able to write down the isomorphism yourself.

Comment: @MikeMiller This field is an extension of $\mathbb{F}_2$ right? so is suffices to show an irreducible quadratic polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ and the quotient give us the field of four elements. You know I'm also learning algebra :P

Comment: @JoseAntonio Yes, that's correct. But the OP wants to express it as a quotient of $\Bbb Z[x]$ (which is entirely possible).

Comment: @MikeMille In this case we can use the correspondence theorem  $\mathbb{F}_2[X]/(f)\simeq {\bf{Z}}[X]/(2,f)$ where $f$ is our quadratic irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$

Comment: Right, @JoseAntonio.

Comment: Can i use the isomorphism $f(x)+\langle p\rangle\rightarrow \overline{\rm f(x)}$(coeffients of f(x) modulo p)@MikeMiller

Comment: I never came across the correspondence theorem you stated @JoseAntonio Any source you can please share

Comment: @learnmore I use Michael Artin's book. Let $f:R\to R/I$  the natural homomorphism. There is a correspondence between $$\{I\subset J: J \text{ ideal} \} \leftrightarrow \{ \text{ Ideals of } R/I \}$$

Comment: thanx its ok for me now